# Understanding sort in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am reading two datasets of sizes 9.5GB (df1) and 715.1MB(df2) on disk.

- I merge them on a key and then run a global aggregation on a resultant column
- This triggers a shuffle and then the shuffled results are sort merged together on the reduce side (This happens internally)

I was trying to get the sort stage to spill some data on the disk and for that I progressively reduced the executor sizes.

As I reduced the executor size, the **stage started to consume more time and less memory and minimized the spill**. Numbers to look at in the images below are a. "duration" that is right underneath the WholeStageCodegen and, b. peak memory total in the "sort" box

- config("spark.executor.instances","6").
  config("spark.executor.memory","6G").
  config("spark.executormemoryOverhead","2G").
  config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","2G").
  config("spark.executor.pyspark.memory","2G")

[image]

- config("spark.executor.instances","6").
  config("spark.executor.memory","4G").
  config("spark.executormemoryOverhead","2G").
  config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","2G").
  config("spark.executor.pyspark.memory","2G")

[image]

- config("spark.executor.instances","6").
  config("spark.executor.memory","2G").
  config("spark.executormemoryOverhead","2G").
  config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","2G").
  config("spark.executor.pyspark.memory","2G")

[image]

I have spark.sql.adaptive.enabled set to False. I have not touched the shuffle partitions. It remains the default 200 throughout

Questions:

1. As you can see increasing the executor size did two things: Reduced the memory footprint (peak memory total) and increased the duration. What is happening under the hood? How is this brought about?
2. I am seeing a duration mentioned right underneath the WholeStageCodegen. I used to think that is the runtime statistics of the entire JAVA wholestagecode generated for the stage. But, here a) There is just one duration given for the second data. There are no statistics like min, med, max as are there for the first data. Why is that so? Also, What is the difference between the sort time total mentioned inside the Sort box and the duration mentioned underneath the WholeStageCodegen?